# Nested ActivityDesigner execution

Tags: .net-4.0, workflow-foundation-4, activitydesigner

I have two custom NativeActivity (Root and Final) with respective ActivityDesigner:
[image]

In the Root NativeActivity I have:

```
[ContentProperty("Body")]
[Designer(typeof(RootActivityDesigner))]
public class RootActivity : NativeActivity
{
  public Activity Body { get; set; }

  protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
  {
    if (this.Body != null)
    {
      context.ScheduleActivity(this.Body);
    }
  }
}
```

and the Final NativeActivity I have:

```
[Designer(typeof(FinalActivityDesigner))]
public class FinalActivity : NativeActivity
{
  protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
  {
    //Do Stuff
  }
}
```

So when I create a new workflow I drag first RootActivity and than drag other activities inside Root Body and all works fine except FinalActivity that doesn't being execute, so "do stuff" doens't hit.

What is wrong?

I have to call context.ScheduleActivity(this.Body); for FinalActivity too?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Where is FinalActivity located in the tree. From the designer it looks like it is part of RootActivity but it's source code doesn't contain references FinalActivity anywhere.

Comment: Is at the bottom of the tree. Here is the designer markup:

<Grid>
        <sap:WorkflowItemPresenter Item="{Binding Path=ModelItem.Body}" HintText="body"/>
        <my:FinalActivityDesigner Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="FinalActivityDesigner1" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
    </Grid>

Comment: It's the activity tree I am interested again. Who is it's parent as that is the one who is responsible for executing it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where or what Final is, but you *have* to schedule it somehow.  If `RootActivity` is the controlling entity, then you might do something like this

```
public class RootActivity : NativeActivity
{
  public Activity Body { get; set; }
  public Activity Final { get; set; }

  protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
  {
    if (this.Body != null)
    {
      context.ScheduleActivity(this.Body, OnBodyComplete);
    }
  }
    // callback fired after Body completes execution
    private void OnBodyComplete(NativeActivityContext context, 
                                ActivityInstance completedInstance)
    {
        context.ScheduleActivity(Final);
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried to do this, but still doesn't work. On WF Persistance database I found this error:

System.ArgumentNullException -Value cannot be null.  Parameter name: activity.

I have suspect on line
" public Activity Final { get; set; } "

How WF associate Final with my FinalActivity ?